# Register controller and action manual at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, controller, action

Is it possible in `ASP.NET MVC` to register an action in a controller manual? For example i have an instance of a controller and want to register it with an action
at runtime? I need this, because in a special case it is not possible for me,
to let the framework reigster the controller/action via reflection.

**EDIT**

For clarification: I want to write controller and actions in a DLR based language (IronPython). When i do that, it is not possible that controller instances were created at runtime using reflection. So i want to create
the controller instaces on my own if needed.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you give an example of what you're trying to achieve? Is the Controller Action not being registered in the Routing Table?

Comment: The controller will be written in a DLR based language (IronPython). So it can't be accessed via reflection. On App-Startup i want to create all controller instances and register them. So that they are reachable for the asp.net framework.

Comment: A controller instance is created when a request comes in and a particular route specifies that controller. Controllers are not "registered", they are compiled into the application. Please clarify what you are attempting to achieve.

Comment: @NightOwl888 i added some explanations. Thank you!